# std::set in CArray doesn't work if CArray needs to grow

Tags: c++, stl, mfc, c++17, atl

In an `CArray`-Collection, i must to have a `std::set`, and i see that if `CArray` needs to grow,
it crashes by first emplace to the existing set. Because `CArray` uses `memcpy`.

There is the code to reproduce; (VS2019 16.3.8 Debug x64/x86)

```
  std::vector<std::set<int>> _vector;
  _vector.emplace_back();
  _vector.shrink_to_fit();
  _vector[0].emplace(1);
  _vector[0].emplace(2);
  _vector[0].emplace(3);
  _vector.emplace_back();
  _vector[0].emplace(4);
  _vector[0].emplace(5);

  CArray<std::set<int>> _atlarray;
  _atlarray.Add({});
  _atlarray.FreeExtra();
  _atlarray[0].emplace(1);
  _atlarray[0].emplace(2);
  _atlarray[0].emplace(3);
  _atlarray.Add({});
  _atlarray[0].emplace(4);
  _atlarray[0].emplace(5);
```

`std::set` in `std::vector` works of course, cause hier copy constructors of existing elements are called, if element type is not an trivial. But i can not use it for backwards compatibility. (`CArray` serialized, and i don't want to change it)

as a solution i can use that: `CArray<std::unique_ptr<std::set<int>>>`, but my questions are;

- It doesn't crash in release build, why? May i need to test longer in release build to have crash? Or will it work, and is it only debug issue?
- Is there any better workaround?
- I'm afraid of that, in the solution (40 projects) we have same issues, which didn't occur yet. Is there any fix for CArray for the same implementations in future and existing code?

**Edit:** More explanation why not vector:
It is an 25years old project that uses MFC serialization (CArchive)
This CArray collection is an existing collection of a class (in this class i added now this set), which is already in use, and changing it too much work. It is all possible, changing of serialization of this collection an so on.
But in the last 7 years new added code uses stl, and unfortunatly it is a mix of mfc and stl.
If this was the only one that i have to solve, it was not a problem.
I only don't know whether there is another where same issue. I wonder actually if there is a way to fix CArray (by redefining CArray with a fixed array class)

**Edit:**
std::vector does it so;

```
template <class _InIt, class _Alloc>
_Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _Uninitialized_copy(
    const _InIt _First, const _InIt _Last, _Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _Dest, _Alloc& _Al) {
    // copy [_First, _Last) to raw _Dest, using _Al
    // note: only called internally from elsewhere in the STL
    using _Ptrval = typename _Alloc::value_type*;

    auto _UFirst      = _Get_unwrapped(_First);
    const auto _ULast = _Get_unwrapped(_Last);

    if constexpr (conjunction_v<bool_constant<_Ptr_copy_cat<decltype(_UFirst), _Ptrval>::_Really_trivial>,
                      _Uses_default_construct<_Alloc, _Ptrval, decltype(*_UFirst)>>) {
        _Copy_memmove(_UFirst, _ULast, _Unfancy(_Dest));
        _Dest += _ULast - _UFirst;
        (void) _Al;
    } else {
        _Uninitialized_backout_al<_Alloc> _Backout{_Dest, _Al};
        for (; _UFirst != _ULast; ++_UFirst) {
            _Backout._Emplace_back(*_UFirst);
        }

        _Dest = _Backout._Release();
    }

    return _Dest;
}
```

and CArray so;

```
SetSize()
{
...
        TYPE* pNewData = (TYPE*) new BYTE[(size_t)nNewMax * sizeof(TYPE)];

        // copy new data from old
        ::ATL::Checked::memcpy_s(pNewData, (size_t)nNewMax * sizeof(TYPE),
            m_pData, (size_t)m_nSize * sizeof(TYPE));

        // construct remaining elements
        ASSERT(nNewSize > m_nSize);
        memset((void*)(pNewData + m_nSize), 0, (size_t)(nNewSize-m_nSize) * sizeof(TYPE));
        for( int i = 0; i < nNewSize-m_nSize; i++ )
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
            ::new( (void*)( pNewData + m_nSize + i ) ) TYPE;
#pragma pop_macro("new")

        // get rid of old stuff (note: no destructors called)
        delete[] (BYTE*)m_pData;
        m_pData = pNewData;
        m_nSize = nNewSize;
        m_nMaxSize = nNewMax;
...
}
```

Comment: Derive from `CArray` and implement the copy operations.  To be honest, it was brain-dead for MFC to leave out the copy operations.

Comment: *Is there any fix for CArray for the same implementations in future and existing code?* -- The jokes on you.  I don't think the Microsoft engineers use those MFC containers anymore.

Comment: I am not familiar with MFC, but what is the reason to use `CArray` over `std::vector`?

Comment: Fix i meant a fixed class and with a CArray define, simply overwriting it. But i'm not sure how to do it. There is no virtual methods or calls from global namespace. (like SerializeElements i meant)

Comment: @uneven_mark Serialization of existing collection. If i change the collection type, than i need to change document version and too much work. Main problem is if there is another issues like that, cause we are mixing stl and mfc

Comment: *Because CArray uses memcpy.* -- If that's the case, then forget about it.  What else in that class assumes that the type is trivially copyable?  You just have to admit that `CArray` is not meant for the job you're giving it.

Comment: @uneven_mark `CArray` is close to 30 years old, with very little to no changes.   Why any new project would use it is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: There is a workaround in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class?view=vs-2019). (Essentially creating a new `CArray` and copying the old array into it. Not nice, but MFC is very much "C with classes" and not so much C++.)

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz replace `CArray` with `std::vector` and use `CArray` only during serialisation. IOW when reading your file, read the data into a `CArray`, then copy the `CArray` into the `std::vector` and throw the `CArray` away. When writing to the file, do it the other way round

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Could you explain how serialization will work when it's time to actually serialize the contents of an std::set contained in a CArray? The set likely has heap allocated memory that you need to visit to get the contents of the set. And unless I'm mistaken, you need code to enumerate the contents of the set to serialize something like that. CArray serialization was probably designed with POD types in mind.

Comment: @LarryB everything in your comment is correct. There is of course some work to be done

Comment: It is not clear to me how serialization would be different with `std::vector`. If you "serialize" by copying the `CArray` or its underlying array's object representation, then this doesn't work with `std::set` elements in the first place. If you are properly serializing element by element, then `CArray` and `std::vector` behave exactly equal. With trivial types, both `CArray` and `std::vector` are ultimatively pointers to equivalent memory blocks, so their underlying arrays can be `memcpy`ed from one to another in principle after appropriate sizing.